# recursive relationship in Django admin

Tags: recursion, django-models, django-admin, relationship

My model looks like:

```
Class foo(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    parent_foo = models.ForeignKey('self', blank = 'True')
```

Next, I had registered this in admin and tried to add some through admin interface. But error occurs:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/foo/add/
(1048, "Column 'foo_id' cannot be null")
```

Making

```
parent_foo = models.ForeignKey('self', blank='True', null='True')
```

did not helped.

Make just:

```
parent_foo = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

I cant, because admin interface force me to fill field.

Comment: Did you migrate your db to reflect the changes?

Comment: I would suggest adding your import statements to questions if you are having issues with models too.  That may be just me though.

Comment: @allcaps, I know it's dumb, but I didn't migrate changes, after i had changed code in my models. Thanks guys.

Comment: @AlexanderZot I think this is one of those things that happens to all of us once or twice. I added it as an answer.

Comment: @AlexanderZot  Hi Alexander, you should accept allcaps answer to give him credit.  I'm still confused as to how it even worked with model.Model.  Was that a typo?

Comment: @ivan7707 Yes, it was. I wrote this code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to migrate your database, so that your db schema reflects the model.

For all who don't know how that is done: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/

Answer (score 2):

try changing

```
Class foo(model.Model):
```

to

```
Class foo(models.Model):
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: How does it not?  If the models class is not being inherited properly that might cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After I checked out from repo on other machine all worked fine, and I realize that actually I didn't migrate changes in models to database.

Remember, guys, always make migrations and migrate after a bit changes in your models. Don't repeat my mistakes.